# Only one javascript alert in Android WebView, then it stops responding

Tags: android, webview, freeze, toast

I set up a javascript alert() handler in a WebChromeClient for an embedded WebView:

```
@Override
public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, final android.webkit.JsResult result)  
{
  Log.d("alert", message);
  Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(), message, 3000).show();
  return true;
};
```

Unfortunately, this only shows a popup toast once, then the WebView stops responding to any events. I can't even use my menu command to load another page. I don't see errors in LogCat, what could be the problem here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to invoke `cancel()` or `confirm()` on the `JsResult result` parameter.

Comment: Worked like a charm for me. When I see these answers that I did not find in the documentation, I always wonder....How did you come up with it ? Anyway thanks a lot saved me a lot of time !

Answer (score 2):

add this

```
        public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result) {
            result.confirm();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        }
```